# discord.js user specific snowflake id commands

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

so im trying to get my bot to detect a user id to allow a command so a command for only one user and im having a bit of trouble understanding what i am doing wrong

```
run(message) {
    //member id 184191493919997952
if(message.member.id.find('id', '184191493919997952')){
return message.say('True') 

}else{

return message.say('False')




}
}}
```

so ive tried to set it up to check whoever used the command and if their snowflake id isnt equal to the one listed then it should return false but i keep getting a TypeError  am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID is a property of User (which is message.author).
You can directly use "==" to check if it equals to something.

```
run(message) {
    if (message.author.id == "184191493919997952") {
        message.reply("true")
    } else {
        message.reply("false")
    };
};
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id

Also, there is no method called "say" of message.
You can check available methods here (for example, message.reply()):
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message

Comment: that works also for some reason message.say and message.reply both work for me it might be commando